# Jquery как передать данные из масива в не пустые ячейки таблицы

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть массив `count[i]` и таблица с ячейками

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='total'></td>
    <td class='total'>тут</td>
    <td class='total'></td>
    <td class='total'>и тут</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Пытаюсь сделать через `:parent`, но он лезет в ячейки первой строчки

```
$("td.total").each(function(i){
  $(this:parent).html( count[i] );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверяем, что в текущей ячейке что-то есть. Если есть - кладем значение.

```js
var count = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4'];

$("td.total").each(function(i){
    if ($(this).text() != '')    
        $(this).html( count[i] );
});
```

```css
tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td> <td></td> <td></td> <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='total'></td>
    <td class='total'>тут</td>
    <td class='total'></td>
    <td class='total'>и тут</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```